# Grub install devices & Software RAID

Tags: raid, software-raid, grub

Server has a software RAID 1 (sda+sdb) configured as /dev/md0 device.

Later system upgrade was launched and grub updated. Now it promped to select grub unstall devices from the list to finish update:
- /dev/sda
- /dev/sdb
- /dev/md0

What items should be selected in case of RAID 1?

Update. fdisk tells:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1           59343       60801    11719417+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2   *           1       59342   476664583+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1           59343       60801    11719417+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2   *           1       59342   476664583+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install GRUB to both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, so that both devices are bootable. You want this so that the system will still boot if the first drive which the BIOS boots off fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should install it on /dev/md0, so mirroring can occur.

Comment: This won't install to the MBR, which is most likely needed.